# How to calculate total number of combination having sum divisible by a given number.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, divisibility

I have following code.And i want to calculate value of ans.

```
for(i=1;i<31;i++)
for(j=1;j<31;j++)
for(k=1;k<31;k++)
if((i+j+k)%3==0)
{
ans++;
}
cout<<ans;
```

i am thinking like this we are free to chose any value of i and j from 1 to 30 ,so definitely the answer will not be less than 30*30.And after this i am not able to get the rule on the basis of that i can chose value of k. Please suggest me the right approach for a general problem if possible.

Comment: This happens only when one number is a multiple of $3$, and the other two are either both multiples of $3$, or have complementary remainders when divided through it (i.e., $1$ and $2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by `on the basis of that i can chose value of k`. A key observation is, that in the inner loop you add sequential values of $k$ to $i+j$ and therefore the value $k+i+j \mod 3$ cylces through $0,1,2$ and with $0$ for every third $k$. Thus ans is about the product of the loop counts divided by 3, in your example $30\times 30 \times 30 / 3 = 9000$